# JQqery ajax call with parameter not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod, pagemethods

I made a jquery ajax call for calling a static `page method`. It is working fine wihtout any parameter. But if I  put parameter then it does not call to that page method. I have below code.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ItemMaster.aspx/UploadFile',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: {'path':'mydata'},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        }
    });
```

**PAGE METHOD**

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string UploadFile(string path)
    {
        return "Success";
    }
```

Is there any `datatype` mismatching happened?. I warm up google for some time without any success. Please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data object needs to be a JSON string.  Try

```
var dataToSend = JSON.stringify({'path':'mydata'});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ItemMaster.aspx/UploadFile',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: dataToSend,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg.d);
    }
});
```

Be sure to include JSON.js if you are supporting older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The data you are sending is not json. Either remove the content type, or convert the data to json.

I'd remove the content type.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ItemMaster.aspx/UploadFile',
    data: {path:'mydata'}, // you may need to remove the quotes from path here
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg.d);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I used this. But it is giving me `undefined` in alert box. Also breakpoint to the page method does not hit.